# rails 5 "password" disappears from params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, ruby-on-rails-5

(This is *not* about filtered parameters in logfiles.)

I have in my view

> <%= password_field_tag :password, '', autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>

and then in my controller

> @password = params[:password]

In Rails 4 I can use @password to authenticate, all works fine.

In Rails 5, params does NOT contain :password anymore. If I change :password to :password1 in view and controller, all is fine, so somehow :password is filtered out.

I checked for config.filter_parameters (which controles log file filtering) - removed 'password' from it, but it did not influence this behavior.

What am I missing?

Comment: You might need to quit your rails server and restart, did you do that?

Comment: Yes, that does not change anything...

Comment: I'm also seeing this! Did you find a solution?

Comment: I think I figured it out, see below, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0):

May not be the case for the OP but this manifested for me porting an App to Rails 5

This can happen when the parameters are passed into the action at the root level, instead of being scoped: for example for a user registration:

```
params: { email: "best@buddy.com", password: "passw0rd" }
```

The Rails (5 at least) parameter wrapper creates 'magic' nested params under the 'user' key (from the controller name) so by the time it reaches your controller action this is actually what is present:

```
params: { email: "best@buddy.com", password: "passw0rd", user: { email: "best@buddy.com"} }
```

Notice that the email value was copied underneath the user key! This feels like WTF, but I'm sure there are good reasons to do this. It happens in `/actionpack-5.2.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb#250` during `process_action`

But given that this is done it may be a bug that the password is not also copied. But this is filtered out by `request.filteres_parameters.slice(*wrapped_keys)`

So the moral of the story is, nest your form params under the model name.

The reason I assume the OP saw the bug is the use of the password_field_tag which probably creates a :password param outside of the :user namespace key

```
params: { :password => "passw0rd" }
```

Instead of the

```
params: { :user => { :password => "passw0rd" } }
```

The controller is probably looking for :user..:password (If strong params are being used)

The reason this isn't surfacing as an obvious problem for the rest of the form fields is because the parameter wrapping is copying all the others into params[:user]

Mental Note the filtering of the password is possibly based on the Log filtering configuration?